# Is it possible to create a .htaccess rewrite/redirect rule which works like a symlink?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, eclipse-plugin, symlink

I want to publish a eclipse-updatesite in different versions.
All versions will be copied to a server, which i can only access via ftp.

i want to a folder structure like following:

```
myhost.de/storr/releases/0.0.1/       (/kunden/homepages/xx/dxxxx/htdocs/software/storr/releases/0.0.1/)
myhost.de/storr/releases/0.0.2/       (/kunden/homepages/xx/dxxxx/htdocs/software/storr/releases/0.0.2/)
myhost.de/storr/releases/0.0.3/       (/kunden/homepages/xx/dxxxx/htdocs/software/storr/releases/0.0.3/)
myhost.de/storr/latest/               (/kunden/homepages/xx/dxxxx/htdocs/software/storr/latest/)
```

If someone use `myhost.de/software/latest/` he should get all the files out of the latest released version.

I tried to create a symlink and to copy it to the server, but it doesnt worked. i dont have ssh access.

Is it possible to create a .htaccess file which acts like a symlink?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's `Alias` directive closely resembles a symbolic link, please check the documentation for that: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

```
Alias /storr/latest /storr/releases/0.0.3
```

Another option is indeed a rewriting rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?storr/latest /storr/releases/0.0.3 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

Both rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the modules needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host (mod_alias or mod_rewrite). In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: thank you, but im getting status 500 with both. unfortunately, i dont have access to the error-log.

Comment: You can't implement a system without access to those log entries. That makes no sense. If you are using a service provider then _ask_ them for thos entries. They _have to_ offer you some form of access. Without those log entries there is no way for you to know where to even start searching for a possible cause.

Comment: I got your solution running/working in a docker container and will switch the provider.